# Check firebase database data is retrieved

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanna know if Firebase data is retrieved.

For example:

```
database.child("name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String name = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            //if(data.isdownloaded){Send data to another fragment via bundle}
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Is there any complete listener for this?

Comment: data changes are never complete, they can keep occurring forever. It would not make sense to be able to listen for completion

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes i know that but what i wanna download is specific data its always same unless user change it. I just wanna know if my string is filled with the data that i just downloded.

Comment: @TimCastelijns listener for databse is not usefull maybe but what about a string listener.If my string is different than null then i can do what i want

Answer (score 0):

you can add a `if statement` inside the `onDataChange()` if you data is retrieved that `true` will be pass to `if` as code below

```
database.child("name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) // add this if statement
          {
             ............ rest of the code
          }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Hope this is helping